# Pick specific text automatically from SMS in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to verify 6 digit number through my APP. I would like to do this automatically once I receive a specific text message.

I have a separate broadcast receiver file that can receive message. I receive it and then stop the Broadcast Receiver.

I have two issues:

1. I am not sure on how to insert the 6 digit number in an activity which is Opened? Do I need to put the 6 digit in some shared preference and keep checking if there is any value using a timer from the activity?
2. I am not sure on how to extract the 6 digit from SMS? The text format is this: "xxxx is the One Time Password (OTP) for your mobile number."

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: a 4 digit one-time password? seems secure.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure on how to insert the 4 digit number in an activity which is Opened? Do I need to put the 4 digit in some shared preference and keep checking if there is any value using a timer from the activity?

Register your SMS BroadcastReceiver in `onResume` of the activity where you want to do some operation and unregister in `onPause` of it.

> I am not sure on how to extract the 4 digit from SMS? The text format is this: "xxxx is the One Time Password (OTP) for your mobile number."

```
public void onReceiver(Context context, Intent intent){
    Object[] pdus=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
    SmsMessage shortMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

    Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message text: "+
       shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()); // Here you get body of it, extract data whatever you need.
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. So do you mean I have to do the above in the same active where I have the textField to enter the 4 digits? Right Now I have a seperate broad cast receiver class? And also I have the message already. I am not sure how extract the data?

Comment: Yes do in that activity wherever is required.. I shared a code to get body of SMS also.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific reason why I have to create the broadcastReceiver in the same activity?

Comment: @TheDevMan If you create a `BR` as a different activity, it will receive all the messages over the lifetime of your `Application` which isn't what you want. You want this `Broadcast Receiver` only to live when this specific activity is open.